# Property 'create' does not exist on type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, frontend

I am trying to contact an API but when I use `axios.create()` I get an error saying:

`Property 'create' does not exist on type 'typeof import("Stuff/Stuff/Stuff/My_app/Frontend/app/node_modules/axios/index")`

Code:

```js
import axios from "axios";

//Error here:
axios.create({
baseURL:"http://MyFantasticAPI.com(Not a real api)"
});
```

Comment: [Seems to work fine for me](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAQwB7AgZzgMyhEcBEyqa+A3ALABQVA9DQKJQ5RwAWAplOwFxVHoA6AMZcEMdgAoA3lThwARgjTsAqgCUAMt3ysYMMNzoBZAJ4AxBADsYSmMCEBBAAoBJYbgkA5CPARxRADaIYMAAlPhUAL6hpEA) Are you sure you have installed the module in your environment? (via `npm`, `yarn` etc)

Comment: I'll try anyway thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
const instance = axios.default.create({
    baseURL: 'http://MyFantasticAPI'
  });
```